# Find out what's become of my YouTube user report

Tags: youtube

A few days ago I reported a user to YouTube support. Now I can't remember what the username was, but I'd like to know what YouTube decided to do about my report.

However, I can't find any menu item or link pointing to the history of my report activities or anything like that in my YouTube account.

I still have the report URL in my browser history, which is like `https://www.youtube.com/reportabuse?report_abuse_type=S&u=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` actually being a different code, here masked for privacy), so I assume that's some (YouTube-internal) user id: maybe I can somehow obtain the username from that and deduce what they decided to do, based on the current user existence, but I don't really know how.

Anyway a real tracking of reports status would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Viewing reported users is not available for end customers. All you can get is viewing your reported history which can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/reporthistory**

[image]

> View your Reporting History
>   YouTube reviews user flags to determine whether or not videos violate
>   our Community Guidelines. Visit your Reporting History page to see the
>   current status of videos you have flagged on YouTube:
>
> - **Active**: videos that are either not yet reviewed or that we determined
>     don’t violate YouTube community guidelines.
> - **Removed**: videos that have
>     been removed from YouTube.
> - **Restricted**: videos that have been placed in
>     one of several restricted states such as age-restriction or Limited
>     Features. Some videos may also appear with the text “Information about
>     this video isn’t available”. This could be because the video was
>     removed by the creator, or is not available on YouTube for a reason
>     other than your report (for example, if it is not available in your
>     country).
>
> Flagged videos are listed in the order you flagged them, from newest
>   to oldest. If you flag a video multiple times, it will appear only
>   once, in order of the last time you most recently flagged it.
>
> In some instances, the video you flagged may not appear in the
>   Reporting History page. This means that many other users have already
>   flagged the video a significant number of times, and that we are
>   already evaluating the video based on these previous flags. We will
>   improve this feature in the future and all of your flags will be
>   included in this report, regardless of how many times a video has been
>   flagged.

- **[https://support.google.com/youtube/1](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7687979?hl=en&ref_topic=2803138)**
- **[https://support.google.com/youtube/2](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802027)**
- **[https://www.youtube.com/watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK8qRNSmhEU)**

Comment: Unfortunately that page seems to list only *videos* I reported, not *users*. At least in my case it does not contain them.

Comment: @LucioCrusca thats all you can get. viewing reported users is not avail for end user (you)

Comment: so your answer does not actually answer my question, but your last comment does. If you edit your answer accordingly, I can accept it.